# Tesseract script error

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

Tesseract works fine via putty with this command line "/usr/bin/tesseract image.tif file" but it doesn't working from the php script:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/convert image.jpg image.tif");
exec("/usr/bin/tesseract image.tif file ");
$f=fopen("file","r");
```

I have only image.tif converted by imagemagick :/

Anyone has ideas about this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the recognition takes more time than it takes to the script to pass on to the next line.
+

> Tesseract adds a txt extension automatically, so in this example, the recognized text would be in file.txt.